# foundation watch is not working. and also app.css is empyt. first I install foundation, afte that I install yarn and other requirements like video

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation

I spend 1 hour to find the error but I cant fix it. please help me  everything is working but foundation work is not working

below err msg

```
User@WIN-QMI0VTE9N70 MINGW64 /d/web projects/notknown
$ foundation watch
C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\foundation-cli\lib\commands\watch.js:26
    npm.commands.start.apply(this, []);
                       ^

TypeError: npm.commands.start.apply is not a function
    at C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\foundation-cli\lib\commands\watch.js:26:24
```

Comment: Which version of Node.js and npm are you running? I googled your error and found this discussion. https://github.com/foundation/foundation-sites/discussions/12321

Comment: @AKX this is my node version v16.14.0

Comment: I just install node and other packages. everything is fresh